# Adding a plot to a graph with the kivy language

Tags: python, graph, kivy

I'm having trouble adding plot to a graph through the Kivy language. Below is my code, it outputs the graph but without the points on it.

```
<CreateGraph>:
    Graph:
        plot: MeshLinePlot(color = [0,0,0,1], points = [(0,35),(1,36),(2,34),(3,37),(4,40),(5,30)])
        x_ticks_major:1
        y_ticks_major:4
        padding:5
        xmin:0
        xmax:5
        ymin:32
        ymax:44
        pos: self.parent.pos
        size: self.parent.size
```